# Segmentation fault occurs when I'm accessing a struct's member

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

A `segmentation fault` occurs when I want to access or modify the value of a struct member in C programming language.

I actually write a battleship networked game in C language (it is a student project). I have a structure named `Player`:

```
enum state{PLAYING = 0, WINNER = 1, LOOSER = 2};
enum action{ATTACK = 1, WAIT = 0, NOTHING = -1};
typedef struct Player Player;
struct Player
{
    enum action action;
    enum state state;
    char name[25];
    int isFirstPlayer;
    Client* client;
    Server* server;
    Boards* boards;
};
```

the main function.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        errorUsage();
    }

    // Initialise player
    Player player = newPlayer();
    // I removed the network initialization here.

    // play game
    play_game(&player);
}
```

the `segmentation fault` occurs in the function `play_game(Player* p)`:

```
void attack(Player* p)
{
    char msg[2];
    bzero(msg, strlen(msg));
    printf("Where do you want to fire?");
    scanf("%s", msg);

    while(verifyEntryAttack(msg) != 1)
    {
        printf("ERROR Entry:\nFormat = A4, C9, ...\nColumns = A B C D E F G H I J\nRows = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n");
        printf("please try again: ");
        scanf("%s", msg);
    }
    sendData(p, msg);
    Box my_attack_box;
    my_attack_box.abs = msg[0];
    my_attack_box.ord = msg[1]-'0';
    updateMarkBoard(p, my_attack_box);
}

void receiveAttack(Player* p)
{
    char received_attack[2];
    receiveData(p, received_attack);
    printf("I have received the attack: %s\n", received_attack);
    Box my_attack_box;
    my_attack_box.abs = received_attack[0];
    my_attack_box.ord = received_attack[1]-'0';
    endureAttack(my_attack_box, p);
}

void play_game(Player* p)
{
    while(p->state == PLAYING){
        printPlayer(p); //print the game boards.
        if(p->action == ATTACK){
            printf("Your turn to attack.\n");
            attack(p); //attack the ennemy
            printf("end of attack turn.\n");
        } else if(p->action == WAIT){
            printf("wait for an attack...\n");
            receiveAttack(p); //receive the attack from the ennemy.
            printf("end of waiting turn.\n");
        }

        if(p->action == WAIT){
            p->action = ATTACK;
        } 
        else{
            p->action = WAIT;
        }
    }
}
```

After one turn in the while loop, the program says "segmentation fault". My tests show that is the `p->action` which is the problem.

See below the program output that shows the problem: [outputs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLGtk.png).
The entire code is available here: [GitLab repo link](https://gitlab.com/RicodeL/battlesheep).
It's like my program can't access the `action` member of my player.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what are the sources of `attack()` `receiveAttack()` `printPlayer()` and `newPlayer()` ? at which _exactly_ line does the seg failt occur? You can even get to that information using printf....

Comment: That's `LOSER`, not `LOOSER`, by the way.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, including the functions (or shortened down versions of them, not forgetting `newPlayer`). Also please try to [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), at the very least try to locate when and where the crash happens (and tell us about it). Lastly please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: "_My tests show that is the p->action_" that means _p_ contains a non valid address. Look at _valgrind_ to find your problem

Comment: When `p->action == NOTHING` this executes: `else{ p->action = WAIT;}` so is the `struct` set up correctly for this state change?

Comment: I add some code and an execution instance. You can also look at the git repo for the sources. I'll look for Valgrind. The `action` member is initialized at ATTACK or WAIT (it depends which player plays first). Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char msg[2];
bzero(msg, strlen(msg));
```

Okay, so here you try to calculate the length of an uninitialized string, a typical source of page faults (and kernel vulnerabilities). `strlen` does not know your array's size, it simply looks for a zero character and is likely to get out of your page very soon. Even if the program does not crash at this point, `bzero` will do the trick as it is likely to *write* memory out of your reach.

Note that a cell is usually described with at least two characters ("C4" or so), so `scanf` will write the terminating zero character past the end of `msg` (again, this could be even out of your available memory). Increase `msg`'s size so that it can accommodate at least valid inputs (at least three chars, the more the better). And you don't need to call `strlen` here; if you want to pre-clear your array, the simplest way would be to initialize it properly: `char msg[256] = {'\0'};`.

Next, you haven't shown your `NewPlayer()`'s code, but your struct contains three pointer fields, please double-check they are allocated, and initialized, properly.

Comment: Declaring `msg[]` as only two chars wide is just asking for trouble, especially since it's on the stack. If you must use `scanf()`, at least declare it to be something safer, such as `msg[80+1]`.

Comment: Okay I replace my `bzero` and it works!  thanks! But I have one more question: when use `bzero`?

Comment: @LouisSinger That is but a design choice with no strict triggers.